# Spring Batch Jobinstancealreadycompleteexception

Tags: spring, unix, spring-batch

I have spring batch maven project deployed in a unix server.

I know that there are a couple of questions on this topic already and I have tried all those solutions. I have tried adding the date and even the time in milliseconds as a job parameter to keep it unique. I am testing something and I have to keep triggering the job manually a lot of times in a day. I have created a folder in a unix server and I have compiled my spring maven project into a jar file and moved it to the server. But whenever I run the spring batch job there by giving a time in application.properties it gives me the Jobinstancealreadycompleteexception.

One more surprising thing is that this issue does not happen in local, only in the server.

Comment: Could you post code and exception in detail

Comment: Probably your job is not taking into account the date parameter? Please share your job and app config to be able to help you.